# creating index columns with python

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

As a minimal working example, I have a file.txt containing a list of numbers:

```
1.1
2.1
3.1
4.1
5.1
6.1
7.1
8.1
```

which actually should be presented with indices that makes it a 3D array

```
0   0   1.1
1   0   2.1
0   1   3.1
1   1   4.1
0   2   5.1
1   2   6.1
0   3   7.1
1   3   8.1
```

I want to import the 3D array into python and have been using bash to generate the indices and then pasting the index to file.txt before importing the resulting full.txt in python using pandas:

```
for ((y=0;y<=3;y++)); do
    for ((x=0;x<=1;x++)); do
        echo -e "$x\t$y" 
        done
    done
done > index.txt
paste index.txt file.txt> full.txt
```

The writing of index.txt has been slow in my actual code, which has x up to 9000 and y up to 5000. Is there a way to generate the indices into the first 2 columns of a 2D python numpy array so I only need to import the data from file.txt as as the third column?

Comment: I cant grasp, what the input is and what the code shall do

Comment: "which has x up to 9000 and y up to 5000" So you have to generate ~45M rows? What does "slow" mean for you? Also, how is it a 3D array? Where's the 3rd dimension?

Comment: Currently the bash code uses about 5 minutes to write the index.txt of a 10M row system. I think it's the I/O that's limiting the speed, hence if I can simply create an array with the indices, it would be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `pandas` for loading the data and managing columns with different types.
We can generate the indices with [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) with the desired dimensions and `reshape` to match your format.
Then concatenate 'file.txt'.

Creating the index for `(9000,5000)` takes about `950ms` on a colab instance.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x,y = 2,4 # dimensions, also works with 9000,5000 but assumes 'file.txt' has the correct size

pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(np.indices((x,y)).ravel('F').reshape(-1,2), columns=['ind1','ind2']),
    pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None, names=['Value'])
    ], axis=1)
```

Out:

```
   ind1  ind2  Value
0     0     0    1.1
1     1     0    2.1
2     0     1    3.1
3     1     1    4.1
4     0     2    5.1
5     1     2    6.1
6     0     3    7.1
7     1     3    8.1
```

---

#### How this works

First create the indices for your desired dimensions with [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html)

```py
np.indices((2,4))
```

Out:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
```

Which gives us the right indices but in the wrong order.
With [`np.ravel('F')`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) we can specify to `flatten` the array in columns first order

```py
np.indices((2,4)).ravel('F')
```

Out:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3])
```

To get the desired columns [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) into a 2D array with shape `(8,2)`. With `(-1,2)` the first dimension is inferred.

```py
np.indices((2,4)).ravel('F').reshape(-1,2)
```

Out:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 3]])
```

Then convert into a [`dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with columns `ind1` and `ind2`.

---

#### Working with more dimensions

```py
pd.DataFrame(np.indices((2,4,3)).ravel('F').reshape(-1,3)).add_prefix('ind')
```

Out:

```
    ind0  ind1  ind2
0      0     0     0
1      1     0     0
2      0     1     0
3      1     1     0
4      0     2     0
5      1     2     0
6      0     3     0
7      1     3     0
8      0     0     1
9      1     0     1
10     0     1     1
11     1     1     1
12     0     2     1
13     1     2     1
14     0     3     1
15     1     3     1
16     0     0     2
17     1     0     2
18     0     1     2
19     1     1     2
20     0     2     2
21     1     2     2
22     0     3     2
23     1     3     2
```

Comment: Can you explain the pd.DataFrame(np.indices((x,y)).ravel('F').reshape(-1,2), columns=['ind1','ind2']) line? I'm a bit confused with the ravel('F').reshape(-1,2)

Comment: Very nice answer! Def. beats mine in simplicity. I would however value a deeper explanation of the indexing, for future readers

Comment: Added a short explanation how the index is created.

Comment: It's the same syntax. I added an example.

Comment: I managed to figure out the syntax and deleted the question just now. Thanks a lot for the updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example how to create the 3D array from a 1D array. As a dummy i have random numbers. Then it creates tuples of x,y,value.

It takes about a minute for 45M rows

```
from random import randrange

x = 5000
y = 9000

numbers = [randrange(100000,999999) for i in range(x*y)]


array = [(a,b, numbers[b*(x-1)+a]) for a in range(x) for b in range(y)]
```

Output

````
pd.DataFrame(array)
Out[23]: 
             0     1       2
0            0     0  878704
1            0     1  524573
2            0     2  943657
3            0     3  496507
4            0     4  802714```
````

Comment: I'm actually also stuck at how to import the values of file.txt as column 2 of the array. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Jacek What do you mean? The values from file.txt need to be read into `numbers`

Comment: Ah, ok I just realized how the numbers array is read into "array". Let me try

Comment: Does that help, or is something missing for you?

Comment: It works. But I'm looking into Michael Szczesny's answer which is what I had in mind initially. Many thanks still!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to your bash then you can avoid two loops:

Code:

```
for ((y=0;y<=3;y++)); do
    echo -e "0\t$y\n1\t$y"
done
```

Output:

```
0       0
1       0
0       1
1       1
0       2
1       2
0       3
1       3
```

above in python is:

Code:

```
for y in range(4):
    print(f'0\t{y}\n1\t{y}')
```

Output:

```
0       0
1       0
0       1
1       1
0       2
1       2
0       3
1       3
```